# Map function over imagecollection Error

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, sentinel-1

I have sentinel-1 dataset and I want to map Frost filter function on each image in the dataset.
The problem is that when I try to do this. using map, I get the error:

> Required argument (count) missing to function: List.repeat(value,
>   count)
>
> Returns a new list containing value repeated count times.
>
> Args:
>
> value (Object): Undocumented.   count (Integer): Undocumented.

I have tried to insert those values, but it also didn't work and I keep get the same error.

this is my code:

```
var Sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .select('VH','VV','angle')
        .filterDate('2019-10-01', '2020-01-01')
        .filterBounds(geometry);

var clippedSAR= Sentinel1.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
}); 


//Apply Frost filter for speckle correction
function Frost(image, frostDamp, ksize)
// Frost is really a simplified version of GammaMap
// Make sure to pass the frost damp factor (frostDamp) as a NEGATIVE number
{
  // ~~(ksize/2) does integer division in JavaScript
  var distance_kernel = ee.Kernel.euclidean(~~(ksize/2));

  // Square kernel, ksize should be odd (typically 3, 5 or 7)
  var weights = ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(1,ksize),ksize);

  var kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(ksize, ksize, weights, ~~(ksize/2), ~~(ksize/2), false);

  // Get mean and variance
  var mean = image.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), kernel);
  var variance = image.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), kernel);

  var B = variance.multiply(frostDamp).divide(mean.multiply(mean));

  var W = B.exp().reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), distance_kernel);

  return image.multiply(W).reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.sum(), kernel).divide(W.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.sum(), kernel));
}

//this is when I tried to insert values.
var frost_result=clippedSAR.map(Frost(-1,5));

//originally did that:
var frost_result=clippedSAR.map(Frost);
```

My end goal: To map this function on all the images in the image collection and then to create time series.

Edit:

I thought  maybe the error is because I have 2 bands, so I seperated them but still get the same error:

```
var vv=clippedSAR.select('VV');
var vh=clippedSAR.select('VH');

var frost_result=vv.map(Frost(-1,5));

//also tried:
var frost_result=vv.map(Frost);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is, that functions which you pass to `.map()` only take 1 argument and nothing else. So your other parameters of `frostDamp` and `ksize` do not get passed to the function and thus do nothing. That's why you get the error, because `ksize` is not assigned to anything.

You can fix this by wrapping the `map` function into your `Frost` function. Like this:

```
//Apply Frost filter for speckle correction
function Frost(collection, frostDamp, ksize)
// Frost is really a simplified version of GammaMap
// Make sure to pass the frost damp factor (frostDamp) as a NEGATIVE number
{
  return collection.map(function(image){
    // ~~(ksize/2) does integer division in JavaScript
    var distance_kernel = ee.Kernel.euclidean(~~(ksize/2));

    // Square kernel, ksize should be odd (typically 3, 5 or 7)
    var weights = ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(1,ksize),ksize);

    var kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(ksize, ksize, weights, ~~(ksize/2), ~~(ksize/2), false);

    // Get mean and variance
    var mean = image.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), kernel);
    var variance = image.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), kernel);

    var B = variance.multiply(frostDamp).divide(mean.multiply(mean));

    var W = B.exp().reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), distance_kernel);

    return image.multiply(W).reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.sum(), kernel).divide(W.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.sum(), kernel));
  })
}

//this is when I tried to insert values.
var frost_result = Frost(clippedSAR, -1, 5)
```